# SLC didn't self level

Tags: flooring, subfloor, ceramic-tile, self-leveling-concrete

Ok here's the problem...
We are planning to lay ceramic tile in our kitchen. We stripped the old flooring off and down to the plywood subfloor. We secured all the plywood so there is no give to it. There were some low spots so we were advised to use self leveling compound to fix this. We used the primer and poured the SLC (covered the whole floor with it) and now we have tons of high/low spots...it's very uneven! My husband thinks we can just put durock over it and tile on top of that but I'm not so sure. So here's the question...should we sand the SLC down so it's even, count our losses and apply durock over the top and then proceed with tile?

Or, should we mix more SLC (maybe thinner this time so we don't have to trowel so much?) pour it over the top and tile directly over it? (assuming it turns out even this time). If we do apply more SLC and tile directly over it, how thick of a layer should it be? and do we need to apply primer again?

Comment: Sounds like you mixed that way too thick.  The self leveling  compound I've used before pours like a milkshake.

Comment: It seemed like it should have been the right consistency (like thick paint) but I think he trowled it too much